# Copying an object for temporary use from the target of a constant-pointer parameter

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm looking to copy an object pointed to by a pointer-to-const (as an argument) within a function to a temporary, stack-allocated copy, which I can manipulate and do various checks on. How do I go about doing this, without cheating by way of const_cast?

```
bool f(const Foo* foo)
{
    (Create a temporary copy of foo)
    (Manipulate temporary copy of foo to test validity)
    (Output bool)
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you might need `const_cast`? And if you need a local copy, why not pass by value?

Comment: Essentially, I'm getting a compiler error when I try to simply create the temporary object and assign the value of the dereferenced foo-pointer to it: "cannot convert from const foo * to foo *".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is all what your function does,  why not just pass by value?

Comment: Because the object is rather large.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a const pointer, it's a pointer to const. Copying is always just using copy constructor, like this:

```
bool f(const Foo* foo) {
    Foo tmp(*foo);
    // use tmp
    return file_not_found;
}
```

Every time you feel the need to use `const_cast`, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: A properly coded copy constructor will accept a const reference as a parameter. If it requires a non-const, that's either a simple mistake in the header or a really bad code smell.

Comment: The system won't let me accept multiple answers, but your's was really helpful too! Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherBerman: The other one is better choice here, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Foo object in the function, then copy the contents of the argument into it.